# Order Limit Theorem for Functional Limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions defined on a set $A$ and assume $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in A$. Further, let $c$ be a limit point of $A$ and assume that the limits for $f$ and $g$ exist at $c$. Show that $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) \le \lim_{x\to c} g(x)$$.

I know that it makes sense I'm just not sure how to prove it

Comment: Suggest you include the exact wording of the definition of limit you are using. For example, are you working in the reals, in an arbitrary metric space, or where? Also for a limit to exist at $c$ is it assumed $f$ is defined on a set of values having limit point $c$?

Comment: i guess it would be the reals, no? and wouldnt the set of values not contain limit point c?

Comment: ovoszn-- Just put an answer for a fairly inclusive case involving functions defined near a point $c$ of the real line.

Answer (score 0):

I first prove the following Lemma: Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$ where for some $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, $\ell \leq f(x)$ for any $x \in A$. I prove $\ell \leq L$.

By properties of our limit, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta$ so that if $|x-a|< \delta$ then $|f(x)-L|< \varepsilon$. One has:
\begin{align*}
-\varepsilon < L-f(x) < \varepsilon &\Rightarrow f(x)- \varepsilon < L \\
&\Rightarrow \ell - \varepsilon < L \\
&\Rightarrow \ell < L + \varepsilon
\end{align*}

By the $\varepsilon$ principle, $\ell \leq L$.

Now we proceed to the final result: Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions with source $A$ and target $\mathbb{R}$, where $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$, and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=K$. If for any $x \in A$, $f(x) \leq g(x)$ then we prove $L \leq K$.

\begin{align*}
f(x) \leq g(x) &\Rightarrow 0 \leq g(x)-f(x) \\
&\Rightarrow  0 \leq \lim_{x\to a}\left( g(x) - f(x) \right) \\
&\Rightarrow 0 \leq K- L \\
&\Rightarrow L \leq K
\end{align*}

Using substitution gives something that looks more similar to what I believe OP was asking for, which is that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \leq \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

This is for interpreting the question as having $f,g$ functions defined on a set $A$ of reals including all $x$ near but not (necessarily) equal to $c.$ Let the limits as $x \to c$ of $f,g$ be respectively denoted $F,G,$ and recall one is assuming $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in A.$

We wish to show the claim that $F \le G.$ Setting things up for a contradiction proof, we assume to the contrary that $F>G.$ Now define $H=(F+G)/2,$ and note since $f(x) \to F$ there is $\delta_1>0$ for which $f(x)>H$ as long as $|x-c|<\delta_1.$ [Apply here that $f \to F >H.$] Similarly there is $\delta_2$ for which $g(x)<H$ as long as $|x-c|<\delta_2.$ Then if $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ and $|x-c|<\delta,$ we have both $f(x)>H$ and $g(x)<H.$ Combining these gives $g(x)<H<f(x),$ i.e. $g(x)<f(x),$ going against our assumption that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in A.$